# \columncolor inconsistency

Tags: columns, colortbl

I'm using column color to visually highlight the first column of a regression table. First row the parameter, second row in "tiny" font the confidence intervals. I'd like the whole column to be colored but it seems only to color the first row of the column and not the second (I guess because I so radically change the font). Visually, the result is horrible. Any suggestions as to how I can get a continuuos color scale down the column. Code+screen shot below. Thanks.

[image: table]

```
... \usepackage{colortbl}...

\begin{tabular}{p{.8in}>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}p{.5in}p{.5in}}\hline
$\sigma$ & 1.237 & 1.098\\
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\tiny \{1.197,1.276\}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\tiny \{1.096,1.100\}} \\\hline
$\sigma$ & 1.237 & 1.098\\
 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\tiny \{1.197,1.276\}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\tiny \{1.096,1.100\}} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: It looks like you can simply remove the\multicolumn

Answer (score 2):

Remove the  `\multicolumn`s: you don't need them since font commands are local to table cells.

*Unrelated*: `\tiny` size  is almost unreadable. I suggest using at least `\scriptsize`, enlarging a bit the column widths:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{.8in}>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}p{.65in}p{.65in}}\hline
$\sigma$ & 1.237 & 1.098\\
& \scriptsize \{1.197,1.276\} & \scriptsize\{1.096,1.100\} \\\hline
$\sigma$ & 1.237 & 1.098\\
 & \scriptsize \{1.197,1.276\} & \scriptsize \{1.096,1.100\} \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]